# How to divide an input file into shards/files for MapReduce

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mapreduce, word-count

So im working on the wordcount program using a Map Reduce framework, and I finally understand how it works and what I need to implement. But I'm confused as to how to divide a single input into different shards, and then assigning a map worker using threads to each shard. I know you can create different files using the Linux command split, but I dont understand how to assign a map worker to each file then from the main file

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  The InputFormat you use will take care of that automatically.